# Roslyn seems to ignore some metadata references

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

During the preparation stage of some integration testing, I have to dynamically generate some assemblies with references to other assemblies and flush them to disk. The obvious choice for this task is Roslyn I guess.
Roslyn compilation completes successfully and emitted assemblies saved to disk. When I check the result using ILSPy, I see that some assembly references are not included.

Dummy class generation code:

```
public static string GenerateEmptyPublicClass([NotNull] string @namespace, [NotNull] string className)
        {
            if (@namespace == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@namespace));
            if (className == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(className));

            var classDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration(className).AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));
            var namespaceDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseName(@namespace)).NormalizeWhitespace();
            namespaceDeclaration = namespaceDeclaration.AddMembers(classDeclaration);
            return namespaceDeclaration.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
        }
```

Assembly preparation code:

```
blic static void GenerateAssembly([NotNull] this string sourceCode, [NotNull] string assemblyFilePath,
            [NotNull] params string[] referencedAssemblyPaths)
        {
            if (sourceCode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourceCode));
            if (assemblyFilePath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assemblyFilePath));

            var assemblyFileName = Path.GetFileName(assemblyFilePath);
            var outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFilePath);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);

            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
            var referencedAssemblyMetadata =
                referencedAssemblyPaths.Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x).WithProperties(new MetadataReferenceProperties()));
            var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyFileName, new[] {syntaxTree}, referencedAssemblyMetadata, compilationOptions);

            using (var fs = File.Create(assemblyFilePath))
            {
                var emitResult = compilation.Emit(fs);
                if (!emitResult.Success)
                {
                    var failures = emitResult.Diagnostics.Where(x => x.IsWarningAsError || x.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
                    var errorReport = failures.Select(x => $"{x.Id}: {x.GetMessage()}, {x.Location}");
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to compile source code {sourceCode}. Report: {errorReport}");
                }

                fs.Flush();
            }
        }
```

For simplicity, I want to generate two assemblies:

- B with the only dependency to netstandard.dll
- A with references both to netstandard.dll and B

Here goes the code:

```
  var emptyClassSourceCode = RoslynAssemblyGenerator.GenerateEmptyPublicClass("DummyNamespace", "DummyClass");
            var standardAssemblyLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Common.ExecutingAssemblyFullPath), "Resources", "netstandard.dll");

            // A references B
            var aPath = Path.Combine(AssemblyGenerationPath, "A.dll");
            var bPath = Path.Combine(AssemblyGenerationPath, "B.dll");
            emptyClassSourceCode.GenerateAssembly(bPath, standardAssemblyLocation);
            emptyClassSourceCode.GenerateAssembly(aPath, bPath, standardAssemblyLocation);
```

B is generated as expected, but A does not refer to B:

[image]

Can't figure out what have I missed, why B is not referenced by A.

Comment: I do not see where your assembly A refer to B. It just have empty class, which not reference anything from B.

Comment: referencedAssemblyMetadata is created from the paths to the target assemblies and then passed to the compilation as a 3rd argument. I think when I pass assembly metadata to the compilation, assembly added as a reference. Am i wrong?

Comment: You just pass the path to assemblies where to look for metadata, but if you does not use any metadata from them, why them should be added as reference?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I've changed code to emit method that simply creates an instance of a class from different assembly and got expected result: B referenced by A. Thank you!

Comment: But what if I know that instance of a class from different assembly will be instantiated at runtime via reflection, for example. As I understand, in this case I have to reference assembly B from assembly A. How could I do this via Roslyn (assembly A might not contain any code which could indicate assembly B compile time)?

Comment: *As I understand, in this case I have to reference assembly B from assembly A.* How that even suppose to work with plugin system, for example? Main application should explicitly reference to all plugin's assemblies (some of which may not yet exist when main application is build)? If it were that way, it would be overly restrictive and not practical, to be useful.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PetSerAl mentioned in the comment, in order to reference assembly we need not only indicate assembly location but actually use its metadata.

Comment: I don't see any comments from PetSerAl. Were they removed? What was the answer? I'm running into this issue too.

Comment: Read comments from user4003407. You should not only specify the location where to find other assemblies but actually use other assembly's metadata in your code.